# I deleted my git project from Eclipse, how can I open it again and sync?

Tags: android, eclipse, git, synchronization, egit

I just used Eclipse and Egit in order to make my first open source project.
This was working pretty well and I made some commits and push during a few weeks.

Now, I have my Android project in my git folder (localy) with some unpushed commits.
Due to some bad manipulations, I removed my project from Eclipse, and I would like to import ir again and push the commits I made.

First thing I tried was to "import" an existing project and pointed the folder of my application, that worked but I lost all my "team" tab and cannot push again.
all the git informations are not linked. (no commits, no push,...)

I also tried to start a new project and choose "from existing source" but with the same result.

Thank a lot for any help.

Comment: Do you have other directories like '`src`', '`.settings`', ... in the same parent directory than your `.git` directory? `.git` contains the repo with its full history, as compressed packaged object, it doesn't contain the sources directly readable.

Comment: I have in level 1: MyProjectDirectory and .git Then, in .git: branches, hooks, lig, etc... and in My folder: res, gen,bin, assets,.. Like a classic Android project. I don't find any .settings file in any directory.

Comment: Do you have in your `MyProjectDirectory` your sources, as well as a `.project` and a `.classpath` file? Because if you do, you should be able to import your project by pointing eclipse to that `MyProjectDirectory`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer myself. 
I had to right click on the project, select team, then share.

At this place I had to fill with Github repository, was not so intuitive, but I did it.